# ChromiumWebbrowser javascript functions missing

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have got a `ChromiumWebBrowser` Control in my WPF application but for some reason, the functions `ExecuteScriptAsync` and `EvaluateScriptAsync` are not available when I try to write them in Visual Studio.

Although when I type `CefSharp.WebBrowserExtensions.ExecuteScriptAsync()` this does exist.

I have also downloaded the repository and compiled the example wpf and tried to reference those DLLs in my project but still getting the same result.

Comment: Have you included using CefSharp; in your header?

Comment: Remember they're extension methods.

Comment: Okay, thanks that worked. Though I was looking in the definitions of the methods I didnt know that I had to include just `CefSharp` in my header.... Thanks for helping me with my stupidity :D